# Dynamic icon to Menu items in a navigation View in android

Tags: android, image, menu, navigation-drawer, navigationview

support.design.widget.NavigationView in my Application. I am able to add the Menu items (image + Text ) dynamically to the Navigation view.Images are added from drawable using SetIcon API.But my problem is now I need to add the images dynamically fetching from server. I browsed on google but didn't find any solution on how to do this. SetIcon will take only drawable or resource id as Arguments. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: In what format are you receiving your images?

Comment: Thanks for reply vguzzi. i am getting images in jpg format.Should i need to convert this into bitmap and then in to drawable using bitmapdrawable and assign it to menu.

Comment: No problem! You cannot store JPEG in your application, are you converting it into a Bitmap?

Answer (score 3):

In order to add an Image retrieved from an API call into your `NavigationView` you will have to convert that Image into a `Drawable` (you kind of answered your own question!) :).

To do this you will first have to convert your `ByteArray` into a `Bitmap` like so:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```

And then you can convert that `Bitmap` into a `Drawable` like so:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

After you have your `Drawable` you can update your `Menu` like this:

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(yourNewDrawable);
```

Or if you prefer, keep a reference to the `MenuItem` variable when the `Menu` initializes and change it when you see fit (like when your API call is finished!).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First get the Menu from the NavigationView:

```
Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
```

Then add your item to the menu, remember to get the return MenuItem so you can add the icon later:

```
MenuItem item = menu.add(groupId, menuItemId, Order, "Menu Item 1 Title");
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_some_menu_item_icon); // add icon with drawable resource
```